# Скрипт липкого сайдбара. Ошибка

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет! Есть такой скрипт, который прилепляет блок, а конкретно сайдбар, на странице сайта. Блок сайдбара в файле обернул в классы .sticky-block
   и .sticky-block .inner, чтобы скрипт работал.

```
     <script>
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var sb_m = 60; /* отступ сверху и снизу */
    var mb = 300; /* высота подвала с запасом */ 
    var st = $(window).scrollTop();
    var sb = $(".sticky-block");
    var sbi = $(".sticky-block .inner");
    var sb_ot = sb.offset().top;
    var sbi_ot = sbi.offset().top;
    var sb_h = sb.height();
    if(sb_h + $(document).scrollTop() + sb_m + mb < $(document).height()) {
        if(st > sb_ot) {
            var h = Math.round(st - sb_ot) + sb_m;
            sb.css({"paddingTop" : h});
        }
        else {
            sb.css({"paddingTop" : 0});
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Там где сайдбара нет, он выводит ошибку о том, что нет элемента

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
```

Как можно этой ошибки избежать? На всех страницах сайдбары ставить не вариант, сам в скриптах не очень. Сайт на Wordpress. Спасибо

Comment: Оберните функцию в условие типа if( $(".sidebar").length ){ function(){} }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте 1 строчку `if (sb.length === 0) return;`

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var sb_m = 60; /* отступ сверху и снизу */
    var mb = 300; /* высота подвала с запасом */ 
    var st = $(window).scrollTop();
    var sb = $(".sticky-block");
    if (sb.length === 0) return;
    var sbi = $(".sticky-block .inner");
    var sb_ot = sb.offset().top;
    var sbi_ot = sbi.offset().top;
    var sb_h = sb.height();
    if(sb_h + $(document).scrollTop() + sb_m + mb < $(document).height()) {
        if(st > sb_ot) {
            var h = Math.round(st - sb_ot) + sb_m;
            sb.css({"paddingTop" : h});
        }
        else {
            sb.css({"paddingTop" : 0});
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Очень круто! Спасибо большое!

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.