# Ошибка jquery на сайте Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Привет! На сайте Wordpress есть плагин Ultimate Member. При попытке загрузить аватарку во фронтэнде должно открываться окно, но этого не происходит. Консоль показывает такую ошибку

```
  Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [name=]
    at Function.fa.error (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at fa.tokenize (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at fa.select (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Function.fa (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Function.a.find (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2)
    at n.fn.init.find (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at n.fn.init.a.fn.find (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2)
    at a.fn.init.n.fn.init (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at new a.fn.init (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2)
    at n (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
```

Есть люди, которые с таким уже сталкивались? Можно решить как-нибудь такую проблему?

Нашел проблему в скрипте

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('a[href*=#]').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
        && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var $target = $(this.hash);
            $target = $target.length && $target || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if ($target.length) {
                var targetOffset = $target.offset().top - ($(".sh-sticky-header-active").outerHeight(true)+ 70);
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

И что с ним не так? Может есть решение вроде этого - [вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/771646/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0). В скриптах не селен ксж